# How to create spinning wheel in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I need to create flash spinning wheel as given in tempate at following url.

http://www.templatehelp.com/preset/pr_preview.php?pr_code=JuX0KU&PHPSESSID=a2u3ajvg4d98es2b38hjpu7c71&i=29698

Any help would be useful.

Comment: if you're interested in animating (3D, Physics, Game Dev) with actionscript you might want to consider getting copies of Keith Peters' two books "ActionScript 3.0 Animation - Making Things Move" and "Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Animation"

Comment: Great suggestion, those are excellent books.

Comment: This site is not for suggestions or 'make me this', it's for solving coding problems. If you stumbled upon obstacles trying to make a spinning picture wheel, please ask for help on that and provide things you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Alternativa3D or Peppervision3D for ActionScript3. Also check out http://flashandmath.com for some insight into 3D effects without the aforementioned libraries

This is a tutorial describing exactly what you need: http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/rings/index.html

More interesting rotating gallery tutorials here:

> > http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/cylinouter/index.html
> >
> > http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/spheregallery/index.html
> >
> > http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/cylingallery/index.html